# Unable to return a numpy array from a column of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
      Col_A     Col_B
   0.   1         5
   1.   2         6
   2.   3         7
   3.   4         8
```

I'm trying to do this to pass a and b as variables inside a function I'm defining. For this, a should be a numpy array of the values in column A but I'm not being able to do that.

So far I've tried:

```
a = np.empty(1); a.fill(df[0])
```

But it returns:

> ValueError: Input object to FillWithScalar is not a scalar

Comment: Typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Describe your problem and what you try to do, not why _your_ solution is not working.

Comment: @Erfan thank you for pointing this out, I didn't realise while I was writing the question. I think I've made it more clear now. My issue is that I'm not being able to return a numpy array from a column of a pandas DataFrame

Comment: Take a step back and 1. provide an example dataset (which you already did). 2. Explain what you try to achieve with your data (pass a and b as variables is not what I mean, thats still your solution). 3. Add an expected output based on your example dataset.

Comment: `df['A'].to_numpy()` or `df['A'].values` should return column as a 1d numpy array.

Comment: `np.empty(1)` creates an array with space for **1** float element.  You can only `fill` it with a scalar.

Comment: From the docs: `a.fill` "Fill the array with a scalar value."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the column and turn it into a numpy array using the following:

`a = np.array(df['Col_A'])`